# Redirect output as a different user

Tags: linux, pipe, sudo, redirectstandardoutput

I need to sudo as a different used in order to execute a certain command. I am trying to use strace with it and redirecting the output of that into a file for further analysis. The tricky part is that as the sudo'ed user I don't have permissions to write to the location I want to save my file in. (and without sudo'ing I don't have permission to execute that command to begin with).

So how can I execute my command as user A, and redirect it's output as user B?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with:

`sudo sh -c "command > output.txt"`

In this way you should be able to run any command and write everywhere.

If you really need, for some reason I don't understand, execute the command as user A and write as user B, you can do the following:

`sudo -u A command | sudo -u B tee /somewhere > /dev/null`

Where A and B are the user you want. The `> /dev/null` part is needed only if don't want command output to be redirected on stdout, too.

Comment: What are you doing with those superfluous calls to sh? The whole thing works perfectly well if you just combine `sudo` and `tee` …

Comment: False. `sudo -u nobody ls | sudo -u root tee > /test` and I get `bash: /test: Permission denied`. Actually I can't explain why, but on my system, I need to call sh (or bash). If someone has an explanation, it's welcome.

Comment: That's because you're using `tee` wrong :). Please read the manpage. You provide the file to write to as an /argument/. In your example the piping is done by your own user (as `>` is interpreted from the caller's shell) while with proper use of `tee` the caller of that part is relevant (which would be `root` in this case…)

Comment: Oh thanks. You're right. Updating my answer, and voting for yours, it worth an upvote. :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `tee` for that. The program reads `stdin` and writes the input to one or more files as well as stdout:

```
sudo funny_command | sudo tee output_file > /dev/null
```

/EDIT: Although you already accepted the other (in my eyes inferior) answer I'll just complete this anyhow:

The use cases above can be done like this

```
sudo command | sudo tee output.txt > /dev/null
sudo -u A command | sudo -u B tee output.txt > /dev/null
```

You don't have to use the redirection to `/dev/null` of course.

Comment: Perhaps not relevant to the answer but I just needed to execute this:
echo "the text content" | sudo -u developer tee output.txt

Answer (score 1):

Another option that avoids piping the stuff back and then to `/dev/zero` is

```
sudo command | sudo dd of=output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've misunderstood the original question.

If you want to capture the entire output of `sudo strace foo` then the easiest way is to run `script` first.

If you want to capture the `stderr` of `sudo strace foo` you could try `sudo strace foo 2> >(tee logfile)`.

If you only want to capture the output of `strace` and not of `foo` then you could try `sudo strace -o /dev/fd/3 foo 3> >(tee logfile)`.

If you can't use `3> >` then I think you can still do it with fd redirection.